# The gradient of a function on a Banach space is an element of the dual space

Tags: optimization, banach-spaces, convex-optimization

Can somebody explain me why gradient descent in Banach space does not make sense? As pointed out by Sebastien Bubek in [his blog](https://blogs.princeton.edu/imabandit/2013/04/16/orf523-mirror-descent-part-iii/), the gradient is an element of the dual space $\mathcal{B}^*$. But I cannot see this.

Comment: It says so right in the blog post - the gradient is always a member of the dual space. It's just that in a Hilbert space, the dual space $H^*$ is isomorphic to $H$, so it's usually not a problem.

Comment: Can you explain me intuitively why is gradient calculated in Banach space a member of dual space? Pics would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the gradient $\nabla f$, to begin with? It is an object that we can use to find the directional derivatives of $f$. More precisely, it is a linear map whose argument is a vector $u\in B$ and the output is the  directional derivative  $D_u f$ along that vector.

So, $\nabla f$ is a linear map from space $B$ to real numbers (or complex if you consider complex scalars). This makes it an element of the dual space $B^*$.